# Как убирать Toolbar при скролле с анимацией?

Tags: java, android

Нужно реализовать скрытие\отображение тулбара при прокрутке содержимого. (Так же, как, например, в приложении play store). 
Как можно это реализовать?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <su.gamepoint.opendomofon.pro.sliding.SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>
</LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Вам нужен `CoordinatorLayout`

Comment: Он и используется

Comment: Оберните тепеь тулбар в AppBarLayout, и добавьте нужные атрибуты для ViewPager и тулбар

Comment: Обновил код в шапке, все равно тулбар не скрывается при прокрутке.

Comment: У ViewPager нужен не layout_scrollFlags, a layoutBehavior какой-то.

Answer (score 1):

В корне вашей разметки должен быть `CoordinatorLayout`, а ваш `ToolBar` должен находится внутри `AppBarLayout`.

У `ViewPager`, behavior:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
   android:id="@+id/viewPager"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

И это работает с `RecycleView`, а с `ListView` не работает.

Я по этой статье делал, там на англ, но все просто:
https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/06/23/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scrolling(part3)/

Может помочь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33958878/hide-show-toolbar-programmatically-on-coordinatorlayout

Comment: Вроде получилось, но тулбар скролится только при нажатии по самому тулбару, а если прокручивать всю страницу, он на месте

Comment: @АндрейУжегов чтоб он скролился нужно чтоб все это было в CoordinatorLayout, Toolbar в AppBarLayout, указан behavior и ты скролил RecycleView

Comment: @АндрейУжегов что у тебя в ViewPager?

Comment: <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        ></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

Comment: @АндрейУжегов нет, что ты в ViewPager размещаешь?

Comment: @АндрейУжегов и почему ты внутри CoordinatorLayout LinearLayout положил???

Comment: У меня еще присутствуют табы, ViewPager размещается содержимое этих табов https://codeshare.io/8bAxV

Comment: @АндрейУжегов что ты в ViewPager ложишь?

Comment: в смысле? как выше код скинул, так там и есть